# Reshape a numpy array from [1,2,3,4] into [[1],[2],[3],[4]]

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reshape

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

into:

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

Is there a simple numpy method to do this?

Comment: `np.c_[<your_list_or_array>]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways. You can use the `reshape` method:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
a.reshape(len(a), -1)
```

Or the `reshape` free function:

```
np.reshape(a, (len(a), -1))
```

Or `np.newaxis`:

```
a[:, np.newaxis]
```

All of these give the same output:

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
reshaped_arr = arr.reshape(4,1)
```

**Testing it out:**

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(4)
reshaped_arr = arr.reshape(4,1)
print (reshaped_arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]]
```

Comment: @mm_ Could you elaborate your question? How exactly are you trying to use `np.linspace`, and to do what?

Comment: found my error ;-) Thanks for the answer !